# Virtuemart Call for price form submission allows user to got logged in to the frontend of the website

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart, cms

Virtuemart Call for price form submission allows user to got logged in to the frontend of the website if the user has a account with a submitted email id. how to get resolve this issue?

Comment: Thank you for coming over from Stack Overflow.  I understand that English isn't everyone's first language, but I am struggling to understand what your question/issue is.  Can you possibly [edit] your question and try to expand or reword the problem that you are having?

Answer (score 0):

@Saravanan Do you mean that when a user submits the form and they are already a registered user, they then get logged into the frontend of the website? If this is the case, I do not see why this is a problem unless the wrong permissions are set and give them more control than you would want. For example, it allows them to edit with editor permissions. But please as suggested, give a better example of what you mean.

Comment: Absolutely you're correct zolder. He is already a registered user of the website.

Comment: I am sorry Saravanan but I still fail to see where the problem is. What is happening when this is the case that is upsetting you?

Comment: I'm Sorry Zolder.  Please check with Following Link 
https://wshop.indiaexcite.com/online/index.php/en/shop-1

Comment: I'm Sorry Zolder.  Please check with Following Link 
https://wshop.indiaexcite.com/online/index.php/en/shop-1

Email : logu@gmail.com